# Ubuntu server 18.04 install crashing: attributeError: 'NetworkDev' object has no attribute '_net_info'

Tags: server, 18.04, system-installation

Here is the full error (I was only able to get a screenshot of it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwImo.png

Trying to install Ubuntu server 18.04, and when I get to network setup, doing anything to the network adapter (clicking info, or setting an IP address) causes that error to appear for a fraction of a second. The installation then restarts from the beginning.

DHCP is not an option here, so I have to fix the error in order to install successfully.

I'm running this from inside ESX, so it's a VMXNET3 adapter.

The source of the error is `/snap/subiquity/664/1ib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquitycore/ui/views/network_configure_manual_interface.py`, line 312;

```
result = yaml.dump(device. _net_info.serialize()
AttributeError: ‘'NetworkDev' object has no attribute '_net_info'
```

Comment: I'd verify that the .iso you downloaded was good, by using md5sum or sha256sum checking. Also when booting to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, there should be a menu selection to "check media".

Comment: The sha256 checksum is good

Comment: Did you check the Ubuntu Live media? Install the server with DHCP (even though that's not what you ultimately want) and try and get it running that way first, then come back and change it to static/whatever.

Comment: DHCP is not working, it isn't getting an address, and is refusing to continue.

Comment: Did you check your installation media as I suggested earlier? Describe your network cabling from the server port to the final router/modem. Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open `terminal` and `sudo lshw -C network`... add that text/image to your question.

Comment: See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1001805 and https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&details=1&operatingSystems=244&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc&testConfig=16

Comment: As I already said, yes I did check the media. The links provided say this should be fully compatible with my version of ESXi

Comment: I *think* that you checked your .iso with sha256sum. It wasn't clear that you checked the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB for errors. I also haven't heard feedback to my last two questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this by leaving the "Search domain" blank under manual IPv4.